# Busy hard drive using Vista

Tags: windows-vista

How can I determine what my laptop is doing, these days the H/drive is very busy most of the time without any input from me. I have tried disconnecting the Internet to see if this affects it without any success.

Although the computer is usable at these times it is slow to respond.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Very often it's the indexer.

Comment: Seriously consider ditching vista for win7. You will never look back.

Comment: That is often not an option unless you have spare, unused win7 licence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722173%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (`perfmon.exe`) and create a monitor on disk usage. Let it record for a few minutes and then you can stop it, open the log, and see which files are being accessed.

Here is a [2nd guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) with more information.

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me some time ago that i had windows defender turned on and i was also using a 3rd party antivirus. so the the hdd was really busy as windows defender was scanning in background.

if this applies to you, check this out: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-vista/turn-windows-defender-on-or-off